# C# Visual Studio Data Grid View returning 0 where SQL count is meant to me shown

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

I have this SQL query which work when I run it in SQL Management Studio.

```
select Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType, count(SaleID) numSales
from Products
join ProductTypes on ( ProductTypes.ProductTypeID= Products.ProductTypeID)
join Sales on ( Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
group by Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType
```

It returns this table.

[image]

Am am integrating this in with Visual Studio Data Grid View and am struggling to get the numSales column to work, right now it just shows 0 for everything like this.

[image]

Here is my code for populating the table

```
private void DisplayDashboard()
        {
            string numSalesQuery = "select Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType, count(SaleID) numSales " +
                "from Products join ProductTypes on (ProductTypes.ProductTypeID = Products.ProductTypeID)" +
                "join Sales on (Sales.ProductID = Products.ProductID)" +
                "group by Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType";

            List<_Dashboard> dashList = new List<_Dashboard>();
            try
            {
                // Automatically  open and close the connection
                using (var conn = ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnection())
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(numSalesQuery, conn))
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        //Define the list items
                        var dashboard = new _Dashboard(
                            rdr["ProductName"].ToString(),
                            rdr["ProductType"].ToString(),
                            int.Parse(rdr["numSales"].ToString()));
                        dashList.Add(dashboard);
                    }
                    dgvDashboard.DataSource = dashList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful" + ex);
            }

        }
```

Thanks for any help regarding the issue.

Edit:
Here is the _Dashboard Class

```
namespace Acme_Project.Business_Logic_Layer
{
    public class _Dashboard
    {
        //Declare properties of a Customer

        public String ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
        public int NumSales { get; set; }

        //Declaring Default Constructor
        public _Dashboard() { }

        //Parameterised Constructor
        public _Dashboard(string productname, string productype, int numsales)
        {
            ProductName = productname;
            ProductType = productype;
            NumSales = NumSales;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show _Dashboard class

Comment: updated in the op

Comment: In your constructor, NumSales= numSales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `NumSales = NumSales` to `NumSales = numsales` inside your parameterised constructor